# Best Practice mapping of pages and routes when building dynamic menu in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, menubar

while i'm well awared this topic might have come a number of time, i still think that the perspective from which i'm looking at it is different.

I have a ZF 1.10.8 project whith essentially `ContentController` to manage what i call static pages (not so static anyway) like `about us`, `contact us`, `products` and `NewsController` for articles, tutorials, all writeups.

i've found that having a dynamic menu will solve a lot of complains from the client and gives more freedom changing the content of the site.

currently i only a main menu bar which is a partial (under layouts/scripts/partials/_mainmenu.phtml folder) which i call in every layout that exists in the system.

Now if i go dynamic, and a new link is created let's say `category`, how to map the category page to a route (routes are in  /application/configs/routes.ini) since the url would be the value of the link in the `menu table` in the database?

the first thought is to change everything to `resource` handled by the `NewsController` to even `about us` will be an article in that case.Since those that i referenced as static pages require different view i wouldn't know how to handle them.

I'm kind of uncomfortable with my way of thinking it.

Can anyone point me to the right direction please? How would you do if? how joomla guys do it?

thanks for reading.....

Answer (score 0):

i am using named routes to build links in menu

```
new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc(array(
    'label'      => $category->getTitle(),
    'route'      => 'catalog-category',
    'params'     => array('id' => $category->getId()),
));
```

exact module/controller/action mapping handled by routes
module specific routes defined in module bootstrap.

i cant give you more on this as my current routes implementation are too tricky and fragile. must heavily refactor it first.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, i'm trying to get your perspective.That means that the route category should already exist.what if the user wants a particular url for example `"/category/main/products"` and later want to change it to `"category/latest/items"`.considering that a client is not supposed to have technical background, how would you encapsulate all this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to have a plugin that in `routeStartup()` checks for the existence of the current URI in a database, if the URI is found then the correct route is added using this function:

```
protected function _createRoute($route, $name, $action = "index", $controller = "index", $module = "default", $params)
{
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

    $defaults = array('controller' => $controller,
                      'action' => $action,
                      "module" => $module);

    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route($route, array_merge($defaults, $params));

            $router->addRoute("region", $route);    
}
```

I don't have a limitless number of controllers and modules so the parameters for this function are hard coded into the plugin, but they could easily for stored against the row in the DB to be more dynamic.

Adding the plugin do this means that after `routeStartup()` is complete the new correct route is available for the dispatch operation.